# Confusing to create models class for cascading drop down list using MVC 5 and entity framework code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Below is my State Model class.

```
public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my City Model Class base state, city will fill.

```
 public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("State")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my Registration model class for the registration form which calls State city.

```
  public class Registration
{
    [Key]
    public int Sno { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email Id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile is required.")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int SelectedStateId { get; set; } 
    public int SelectedCityId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entity is required.")]
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string PinCode { get; set; }
    public string accountactivated { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "New Password")]
    [NotMapped]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Confirm New Password")]
    [NotMapped] // Does not effect with your database
    [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "Password not match")]
    public string ConfirmNewPassword { get; set; }

}
```

My question is how should i have to call state and city cascading drop down list in my Registration Model class to generate scaffolding for registration page with dependent drop down list.

Comment: You have `StateId` & `CityId`, therefore use `DropDownListFor` bound to both properties and use `SelectList` for each dropdown's option values. To make `City` options dependent by selected `StateId` value, use AJAX callback and put `CityId` dropdown inside partial view.

Comment: I used this link: https://yogeshdotnet.com/custom-user-registration-form-in-entity-framework-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-example/ and cascading is working fine not able to add require validation to cascading dropdown. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Can't you simply putting both `StateId` & `CityId` in registration viewmodel? Then with that viewmodel you may pass ID values to respective `State` & `City` table class entities (data model & viewmodel classes should be separated).

Comment: Please i am very confuse can you me post code for as a answer and also i given one link there i am not able to add validation for drop-down, any of give me answer with code. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: What do you need is just create 2 properties (`public int SelectedStateId { get; set; }` and `public int SelectedCityId { get; set; }`) in `Registration` viewmodel, bound dropdowns with those properties and all should done if you have POST action like `public ActionResult Register(Registration model)`.

Comment: Please tell me one think this url: https://yogeshdotnet.com/custom-user-registration-form-in-entity-framework-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-example/ already worked for me but  validation is not firing why? and above comment i updated question created 2 properties, now shall i have to do scaffolding then i have to go next with post action?. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Firstly, you d not use data models in views when editing data, you create data models to represent what you need in the view. To create cascading dropdownlists, refer the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: I am not understanding given url: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym can you write your answer into code to understand easyliy. @StephenMuecke